# Unable to install Samba

Tags: samba

I've been trying to install Samba with this terminal prompt:

```
sudo apt-get install samba
```

This is the response I get:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have requested an
impossible situation or if you are using the unstable distribution that some
required packages have not yet been created or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
  samba : Depends: samba-common (= 2:4.1.6+dfsg-1ubuntu2) but 2:4.1.6+dfsg-1ubuntu2.14.04.2 is to be installed
  Depends: samba-common-bin (= 2:4.1.6+dfsg-1ubuntu2) but 2:4.1.6+dfsg-1ubuntu2.14.04.2 is to be installed
  Depends: samba-dsdb-modules but it is not going to be installed
  Depends: samba-libs (= 2:4.1.6+dfsg-1ubuntu2) but 2:4.1.6+dfsg-1ubuntu2.14.04.2 is to be installed
  Recommends: attr but it is not going to be installed
  Recommends: samba-vfs-modules but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Where do I go from here?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I resolve unmet dependencies after adding a PPA?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies-after-adding-a-ppa)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223237/unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages)

Answer (score 0):

first you need to run

> sudo apt-get update

then you can search for the available packages related to samba by typing

> sudo apt-cache search samba | grep samba

also if the package was halfway installed you can fix the broken packages by using the following command

> sudo apt-get -f install

Hope this helps. Good Luck.